# Linear transformation $T$ that satisfy $\operatorname{Image}(T) = \operatorname{Image}(T^2)$ imply $\ker(T)\cap\operatorname{Image}(T)=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be finite dimension vector space and let $T:V \rightarrow V$. Why is it true that  $\operatorname{Image}(T) = \operatorname{Image}(T^2)$ $⟹$ $\ker (T)\cap\operatorname{Image}(T)=0$.

my attempt:
Assume $v\in\ker (T)\cap\operatorname{Image}(T)$ Then $v\in \operatorname{Image}(T^2)$. Therefore, there exist $u,w \in V$ s.t $$T(u)=v$$ $$T^2(w)=v$$ $$T(v)=0$$
From here I have no idea how to show that $v=0$

Comment: There have been several answers, but your comments seem to imply that you are also interested in the infinite dimensional case. Consider $V=\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ and the shift operator $(x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots) \mapsto (x_2, x_3, x_4,\ldots)$.

Comment: I am not intresting in the infinite case since I have not studied it yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $v\in\ker(T)\cap\operatorname{Im}(T)$. Since $v\in\ker(T)$, $T(v)=0$. But $v\in\operatorname{Im}(T)$, and therefore $v=T(w)$, for some vector $w$. Therefore $0=T(v)=T\bigl(T(w)\bigr)$. So, $w\in\ker(T^2)$.

Now, note that $\dim\ker(T)=\dim V-\dim\operatorname{Im}(T)$ and that therefore\begin{align}\dim\ker(T^2)&=\dim V-\dim\operatorname{Im}(T^2)\\&=\dim V-\dim\operatorname{Im}(T)\\&=\dim\ker(T).\end{align}But $\ker(T)\subset\ker(T^2)$, and so, since $\ker(T)$ and $\ker(T^2)$ have the same dimensions, they're equal.

But I proved that $w\in\ker(T^2)$ So, $w\in\ker(T)$, and therefore $v=T(w)=0$.

Comment: The way you present your argument - can it hold for infinite dimensional space? The statement $\mathrm{Im}T=\mathrm{Im}T^2\implies T=T^2$; I am unsure how this behaves for infinite dimensional space.

Comment: This answer is wrong. $ImT = Im T^2$ doesn't imply that $T=T^2$.

Comment: @Compacto I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: @FShrike No, what I did does not work in infinite dimension.

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\im}{\operatorname{Im}}\newcommand{\span}{\operatorname{span}}$In finite dimensional space, a linear transformation is invertible if and only if it is surjective - this follows from the rank nullity theorem. Then $\im(T)=\im(T^2)$ implies that the restriction of $T$ to $\im T$, the map $T:\im T\to\im T^2$, is a surjection and thus a bijection; the kernel of this restriction is trivial.

You then have $\ker T\cap\im T=\{0\}$.

If you want a more "direct" way of seeing this, note that if $u\in\ker T\cap\im T\setminus\{0\}$, then as both $\ker T,\im T$ are linear subspaces we have that $\lambda u\in\ker T\cap\im T$ for all $\lambda\in\Bbb R$ (or whatever field you're working in). Then by the exchange/replacement theorems, I can form a basis of $\im T$ from $u,v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_{n-1}$, where $\dim\im T=n$, and then: $$\im T^2=T(\im T)=\span\{T(u),T(v_1),\cdots\}=\span\{0,T(v_1),\cdots\}=\span\{T(v_1),\cdots\}$$And you get that $\dim\im T^2=\dim\span\{T(v_1),\cdots,T(v_{n-1})\}\le n-1$ but $\dim\im T=n$, so $\im T^2\neq\im T$, a contradiction.

Comment: Just a minor complaint: the intersection of kernel and image of $T$ is a subspace, so it cannot be the empty set (you intend to say it has dimension$~0$ or something equivalent to that). Also, while I'm nitpicking, your second sentence reads "Then [equality of subspaces] implies that the restriction... is a surjection and thus...", but the surjective part is independent of the equality of subspaces; it is the following bijectivity that is implied by that fact.

Answer (score 1):

By dimension counting, this is equivalent to proving that $\ker T + Im(T)= V$.

For every $v\in V$, we have that $T(v) \in ImT^2$, so $T(v) = T^2(u) $ for some $u\in V$, and this means that $0=T(v) -T^2(u) = T(v-T(u))$, so $v- T(u) \in \ker T$, and the identity:

$$v= (v-T(u)) + T(u) $$

Shows immediately that $v$ is sum of a vector in $\ker T$ and a vector in $Im T$.

Answer (score 1):

This result is specific to the finite dimensional situation. Even if you are not interested in the infinite dimensional case, this is a noteworthy point, because it means that your proof needs to use some property specific of finite dimensional spaces (for otherwise your proof would also work in the infinite dimensional case, which it cannot). One such property is that a linear map from a (sub)space to itself is injective if and only if it is surjective. In this situation the restricted map $\def\Im{\operatorname{Image}}\Im(T)\to\Im(T^2)$, which is defined by $T$ and surjective for any linear operator$~T$, is one from the subspace $W=\Im(T)=\Im(T^2)$ to itself. It is therefore (by finite dimension of$~W$) injective, which means in particular that any vector in$~W$ that is mapped to the zero vector is itself necessarily the zero vector. Such vectors are precisely the ones in $\Im(T)\cap\ker(T)$, whence the result.